# In Ubuntu 15.04, boot-repair running forever, trying to fix the system after deleting all kernels

Tags: grub2, kernel, 15.04, lvm, boot-repair

I have deleted all my kernels.

I am trying to fix the problem with [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from live USB

I have LVM enabled

[image: boot repair trying to purge/reinstall kernels]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Once you are in live usb try the following comments

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install lvm2

{IF FILE SYSTEM IS ENCRYPTED => DECRYPT}

vgscan --mknodes                        *##not down the volume name##*
mount /dev/<volume-name>/root /mnt      *## For me 'ubuntu-vg' ##*
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot               *## fdisk -l for right sd--##*

mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
chroot /mnt

apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
update-grub 
apt-get clean
umount /mnt
reboot
```

[DECRYPT] If the file system is encrypted then decrypt

```
apt-get install cryptsetup
modprobe dm-crypt
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 crypt1  *## fdisk -l to get right sd--##*
*##Write the passphrase##*
```

Credits goes to [kyodake](https://askubuntu.com/users/285292/kyodake) for his answer to [How to reinstall kernels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528139/how-to-reinstall-kernels-after-accidental-deletion-with-a-separate-boot-partitio)